# Read blob contents into an existing SharedArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to read the contents of a Blob into an existing SharedArrayBuffer originating is a worker waiting for the buffer to be poplated.  In my case, I can guarantee that the SharedArrayBuffer is at least long enough to hold the entire contents of the Blob.  The best approach I've come up with is:

```
// Assume 'blob' is the blob we are reading
// and 'buffer' is the SharedArrayBuffer.
const fr = new FileReader();
fr.addEventListener('load', e =>
  new Uint8Array(buffer).set(new Uint8Array(e.target.result)));
fr.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

This seems inefficient, especially if the blob being read is relatively large.

Answer (score 1):

`Blob` is not a `Transferable` object. Also, there is no `.readAsSharedArrayBuffer` method available on `FileReader`.

However, if you only need to *read* a `Blob` from multiple workers simultaneously, I believe you can achieve this with `URL.createObjectURL()` and [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), although I have not tested this with multiple workers:

```
// === main thread ===
let objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
worker1.postMessage(objectUrl);
worker2.postMessage(objectUrl);

// === worker 1 & 2 ===
self.onmessage = msg => {
    fetch(msg.data)
        .then(res => res.blob())
        .then(blob => {
            doSomethingWithBlob(blob);
        });
};
```

Otherwise, as far as I can tell, there really isn't an efficient way to load data from a file into a `SharedArrayBuffer`.

I also provide a method here for transferring chunks of a blob from main thread to a single worker. For my use case, the files are too big to read the entire contents into a single array buffer anyway (shared or not), so I use `.slice` to deal in chunks. Something like this will let you deliver tons of data to a single worker in a stream-like fashion via multiple `.postMessage` calls using the `Transferable` `ArrayBuffer`:

```
// === main thread ===
let eof = false;
let nextBuffer = null;
let workerReady = true;

let read = 0;
function nextChunk() {
    let end = read + chunkSize;
    if(end >= file.length) {
        end = file.length;
        eof = true;
    }

    let slice = file.slice(read, end);
    read = end;

    fr.readAsArrayBuffer(slice);
}

fr.onload = event => {
    let ab = event.target.result;

    if(workerReady) {
        worker.postMessage(ab, [ab]);
        workerReady = false;
        if(!eof) nextChunk();
    }
    else {
        nextBuffer = ab;
    }
};

// wait until the worker finished the last chunk
// ... otherwise we'll flood main thread's heap
worker.onmessage = msg => {
    if(nextBuffer) {
        worker.postMessage(nextBuffer, [nextBuffer]);
        nextBuffer = null;
    }
    else if(!eof && msg.ready) {
        nextChunk();
    }
};

nextChunk();


// === worker ===
self.onmessage = msg => {
    let ab = msg.data;
    // ... do stuff with data ...
    self.postMessage({ready:true});
};
```

This will read a chunk of data into an `ArrayBuffer` in the main thread, transfer that to the worker, and then read the next chunk into memory while waiting for worker to process the previous chunk. This basically ensures that both threads stay busy the whole time.

Comment: This seems even more complicated than the readAsArrayBuffer approach.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer